# PHP's json_decode returns empty string (not NULL)

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am sending a stringified JSON through AJAX from the client to the server. However, PHP is unable to decode it even though it seems to be properly structured to me. I've been through answers to similar questions, in most questions `json_decode` returns `NULL` which is not the case here, instead it returns an empty string.

What Javascript sends:

```
{"columns":{"l1":{"name":"Impressions"},"l2":{"name":"Clicks"}},"domain":"Media Performance"}
```

What PHP prints out (same thing with escaped quotes):

```
{\"columns\":{\"l1\":{\"name\":\"Impressions\"},\"l2\":{\"name\":\"Clicks\"}},\"domain\":\"Media Performance\"}
```

Can anyone see the issue here? It seems pretty straightforward but `json_decode` keeps returning an empty string.

My apologies for not posting the code.

Here is the AJAX (`str` is the JS string given above):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base + "handlers/createreport.php",
            data: {
                str: str
            }
        })
```

And here is `createreport.php`, there's no processing whatsoever:

```
$str = $_POST['str'];

echo $str;  //prints out the string given above with escaped quotes
echo json_decode($str);     //empty string
```

Comment: please show your code, simply providing the input and output does not allow us to trouble shoot what is happening

Comment: What php prints out is not valid json, are you processing your input somehow before you try to decode it?

Comment: @cmorrissey I've added JS and PHP code to the question.

Comment: @jeroen No, please see the code I just added above.

Comment: Are you on an old php version that has magic quotes enabled? If so, you should turn that off.

Comment: Wow. Nice catch. I hadn't encountered magic quotes in about 2 years, until just now. It's not my server and I didn't think to check the php.ini settings.

Comment: Are you getting the JSON response back to AJAX? If so, you have to tell AJAX the DataType `DataType: 'JSON'` otherwise you won't get back anything from JSON

Answer (score 0):

The `data` sended in AJAX is received by the server as POST params, so you dont need to decode json, otherwise use it like an array.

I just test it, and works:
`var_dump($_POST['str']);`

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
  'columns' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b>
      'l1' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
        <b>array</b>
          'name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font>  <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Impressions'</font> <i>(length=11)</i>
  'l2' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b>
      'name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small>     <font color='#cc0000'>'Clicks'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
  'domain' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Media Performance'</font> <i>(length=17)</i>
```